# /etc/security/limits.conf not applied

Tags: limit, ulimit

I have `/etc/security/limits.conf`, that seems not been applied:

```
a soft nofile 1048576 # default: 1024
a hard nofile 2097152
a soft noproc 262144  # default 128039
a hard noproc 524288
```

Where `a` is my username, when I run `ulimit -Hn` and `ulimit -Sn`, it shows:

```
4096
1024
```

There's only one other file in the `/etc/security/limits.d` that the content is:

```
scylla  -  core     unlimited
scylla  -  memlock  unlimited
scylla  -  nofile   200000
scylla  -  as       unlimited
scylla  -  nproc    8096
```

I tried also append those values to `/etc/security/limits.conf` then restarting, and do this:

```
echo '
session required pam_limits.so
' | sudo tee -a /etc/pam.d/common-session
```

but it didn't work. My OS is `Ubuntu 17.04`.

Comment: See also https://serverfault.com/questions/569288/ulimit-n-not-changing-values-limits-conf-has-no-effect#853278

Answer (score 21, accepted):

https://superuser.com/questions/1200539/cannot-increase-open-file-limit-past-4096-ubuntu/1200818#_=_

There's a bug since Ubuntu 16 apparently.

Basically:

1. Edit `/etc/systemd/user.conf` for the soft limit, and add `DefaultLimitNOFILE=1048576`.
2. Edit `/etc/systemd/system.conf` for the hard limit, and add `DefaultLimitNOFILE=2097152`.

Credit goes to [@mkasberg](https://superuser.com/users/164984/mkasberg).

Comment: After these settings, do we need restart?

Comment: Yes, a restart was required when I tried it.

Comment: this works to set `ulimit` values, but one thing to notice: systemd has only "infinity" value to set `ulimit` to "unlimited", there is apparently no "unlimited" value in systemd 252 (252-18.el9)

Answer (score 15):

[It is recommended](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/6902da549bfd5313df0802f18fab74d4cc126427/src/core/system.conf.in#L11) to create `/etc/systemd/*.d/` directories instead of editing `/etc/systemd/system.conf` and `/etc/systemd/user.conf` directly.

1. Create a new file `/etc/systemd/system.conf.d/limits.conf` with these contents:

   ```
   [Manager]
   DefaultLimitNOFILE=1048576:2097152
   DefaultLimitNPROC=262144:524288
   ```
2. Run `systemctl daemon-reexec` as root.
3. Logout and login again.
4. Check your new limits with either `ulimit -a` or `ulimit -n` and `ulimit -u` for max open files and max processes, respectively.

Refer to the [`systemd-system.conf` manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-system.conf.html) for details.